# how to remove brackets and single cots in list using python

Tags: python-3.x

**I tried this code**

```
>>> do = [{'no': [0], 'name': ['MSI Afterburner 4.6.2'], 'version': ['4.6.2']}]
>>> flattened = [val for sublist in do for val in sublist]
>>> flattened
```

my output

```
['no', 'name', 'version']
```

**needed output**

```
no:0, name:MSI Afterburner 4.6.2, version: 4.6.2
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is self-explanatory:

```
", ".join(f"{k}: {v[0]}" for k, v in do[0].items())
#'no: 0, name: MSI Afterburner 4.6.2, version: 4.6.2'
```

Comment: tq@DYZ, you saved me.

Comment: what if i have list like this -- do = [{'no': [0], 'name': ['MSI Afterburner 4.6.2'], 'version': ['4.6.2'}, {'no': [1], 'name': ['AnyDesk'], 'version': ['ad 5.4.2']}